# Formatting of inline output: how to enforce format with format() or sprintf()

Tags: r, knitr

[crossposted from http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/sweave/]

I understand and appreciate knitr's policy to format large numbers in scientific notation. However, I have encountered that this happens even if I intensionally use format() to enforce a particular format. knitr seems to override this and I really wonder how this is possible, as both format() returns a character string, right?. Are there any options of format that are globally altered by knitr? Any help is gratefully appreciated!

Cheers, Ulrich

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible for `knitr` to reformat the results from `format()`. As you said, `format()` returns character strings. I do not see how `knitr` overrides the results:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Here is a number \Sexpr{1e10}, and here is \Sexpr{format(1e10)}.
\end{document}
```

[image: inline numbers in knitr]

Comment: Thanks @Yihui for a great package. I have been using `sweave` for a long time, and right now going through the knitr manual. I am just trying my first `knitr` package using the code above. However the above code is not working. It gives me the error `Line 5 Missing $ inserted.', and this statement is given twice. 
I am running the latest version of R, LaTeX, knitr and RStudio on OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Interesting the error comes from using `1e10`. If I use `1.1e10` everything runs fine!!

Comment: @Shambho Sorry that is a known bug in knitr 1.5, which has been fixed in the development version: https://github.com/yihui/knitr